# How can we send Date object to Rest Api in swiftui?

Tags: swift, rest, post, swiftui, http-post

Currently in my DTO class, I am declaring a type like this.

```
var transferDate : Date?

private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {

case transferDate = "TransferDate"
}

override func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws{
try super.encode(to:encode)

try container.encode(transferDate, forKey: .transferDate)
}
```

In my view, I am assigning Date like this

```
Dto.transferDate = self.Date
```

while debugging I see this in debug window

```
(Date) <unavailable; try printing with "vo" or "po"
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to do anything custom for Dates. As I recall, by default the system encodes dates as a Double like the one returned by `Date.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate()`.

If you're writing the RESTFUL API, you should be able to write it to handle that date format.

If you need "internet dates" (date strings in the standard format that includes an offset from UTC) you would need to specify that when setting up your encoder.

Comment: I am using the Datepicker and I want to send the selected date,
using date the api will return me the data.

Comment: That doesn't tell me anything useful. Your override of the encode() function is goign to use the default encoding of dates, which will use the timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate as I described.

Comment: but I don't see any date while debugging even if assign any date.
what would be other way to send the date? do you have any idea?

Comment: What do you mean "I don't see any date while debugging..."?